# Problems enrolling Windows Phone 8.1 client in WSO2 EMM 2.0

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I tried to enroll a Lumia 640 device with Windows Phone 8.1 system and it does not work. the phase when you type the e-mail address ***@hotmail.com and the server address as 192.168.43.51:9443 or 9444, the device does not load settings and displays no exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The EMM client sends requests to the EMM server through a Proxy Server.The Windows EMM protocol constructs a URI that uses the host name by appending the domain of the email address to the subdomain enterpriseenrollment, for the each device request. Therefore you can either purchase a domain name or create a DNS entry in the  **http://enterpriseenrollment.EMAIL_DOMAIN** format.

Could you able to configure the proxy through the server and the device.

Windows Configurations -
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Windows+Configurations
Message flow-
https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM200/Device+Enrolment+Process+Message+Flow

Comment: Thank you for your reply but the documentation is on linux and there is no documentations on windows configuration for apache

Comment: It is just a example.Original requirement is depict in there.Requirement is direct the device calls to server endpoints.

Comment: It is not clear configuring the server endpoints. I cannot find how it works. If there is any more documentation would you please send me the link?

Comment: you can follow up the link to configure proxy in windows environment.

http://hasuniea.blogspot.com/2016/04/apache-proxy-configurations-for-windows.html

Comment: You can refer the http://hasuniea.blogspot.com/2016/04/windows-device-support-in-wso2-emm-200.html post to get idea about the enrollment process.